# Unable to open phpMyAdmin on XAMPP

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

I am facing issues opening phpmyadmin on XAMPP. Any one of you have any idea what might went wrong or how do I fix this problem ?

The error is #2002 - An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.

The server is not responding (or the local server's socket is not correctly configured).

Any help will be much appreciated, thanks

[image: Error]

Comment: if you are in Linux, its important that with which user did u start the xampp service?

Comment: I am using windows 10

Comment: Try the fix posted at this [link.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17707961/2002-no-connection-could-be-made-because-the-target-machine-actively-refused#comment53137045_32644576) Hope it helps