# Unable to query in code, but artisan migrate works

Tags: database-connection, laravel-5.4

I have set up a new Laravel 5.4 project being served by `php artisan serve` with a MySQL database all on a Windows machine (I'm not using Homestead or a VM). I am able to run database migrations just fine using `php artisan migrate`, but if I try to query the database from a Controller (`DB::connection()->select('select * from users');`, for example) I receive the following error:

```
PDOException in Connector.php line 68: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
```

I can't figure out why Laravel is unable to query the database. I have tried the following things:

- I can connect to the database through Sqlyog with the same credentials in my `.env` file.
- I can run `php artisan migrate:reset` and `php artisan migrate` successfully.
- I've tried pointing to both a Microsoft SQL Server running on my local machine as well as a MySQL server running on my local machine. In both cases `php artisan migrate` works fine but I'm not able to run queries through my app.
- I've tried switching the `DB_HOST` variable in my `.env` file between `127.0.0.1` and `localhost` without luck.
- I've tried running `php artisan config:clear` without luck.

Is there a step I'm missing somewhere?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/17707961/3472948

Comment: This ended up resolving itself when I stopped and re-ran `php artisan serve`.