# Xamp Access denied

Tags: mysql, xampp

Error
MySQL said: Documentation

## 2002 - No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

— The server is not responding (or the local server's socket is not correctly configured).
mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed.
mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

I get this error when I start the browser.
Thanks in advance.
Immediate help is appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [#2002 - No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17707961/2002-no-connection-could-be-made-because-the-target-machine-actively-refused)

Answer (score 0):

I have run MYSQL on port 3333, it will change the port inside of config.inc.php file.

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1' 

to   

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1:3333'
```

It works, Fine!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Great, I was trying for last two days.  But no help and guide worked.  After reading your answer, I am happy and it worked.

Xampp/phpmyadmin/Config.inc.php was changed and now works fine.

/* Bind to the localhost ipv4 address and tcp */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1:3307';  #added the port number if it is not 3306 the default
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';