# when I start apache MySQL server, I get error " (HY000/2002): No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it."

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, xampp, localhost

after the start apache server, i could not access PHPMyAdmin. when i try to access i get an error and auto-stop MySQL server.

[image]

```
 - mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No connection could be made
   because the target machine actively refused it.
 - Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed.
   mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No connection could be made
   because the target machine actively refused it.
 - phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server
   rejected the connection..
```

how can i solve this error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [#2002 - No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17707961/2002-no-connection-could-be-made-because-the-target-machine-actively-refused)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add below line under config.inc.php

`$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = 8111;`

Comment: Can you explain this answer? What is this doing? What is the root problem that caused the user to be in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Windows os and the above solution does not work, just check if your mysql is running with "netstat -ano" command, if the services are not running just try starting the mysql service.